# How to define some post values as variable

Tags: rest, testing, automation, cypress

I have a post response like this

```
const requestbody=
        {
        "days": x,
        "amount": x,
        "administrationFee": 2.99,
        "conclusionFee": 100,
        "currency": "EUR"  
        }
```

The days and amount are different each time. How can I define them differently on each request?

I've tried setting them as constant and defining them before each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const requestbody= { "days": 0, "amount": 0, "administrationFee": 2.99, > "conclusionFee": 100, "currency": "EUR"   }  ;

//for each Post

requestbody.days = 10;

requestbody.amount = 1.50;

// Do the Post
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom command to add the values.

That way you will encapsulate the values that remain the same each time you call the command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('requestWith', (days, amount) => {

  const requestbody= { 
    days,                 // from parameter
    amount,               // from parameter
    administrationFee: 2.99, 
    conclusionFee: 100,  
    currency: "EUR"   
  } 
  return cy.request({
    url: 'my-url',
    body: requestBody,
  })
})

cy.requestWith(3, 200)
  .then(response => {
    ...
  })
```

Comment: This solution embodies all Cypress has to offer, I defined this command in command.js and called the "requestWith" out in the test file, but I got > it(...).then is not a function Any ideas?

Comment: The message showing `it().then()` is indicating to me a different problem.